# Erro ao conectar Python ao BD Oracle

Tags: python, oracle

Não estou conseguindo conectar o Python a minha base de dados oracle.

Apresenta o seguinte erro :

```py
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('topm/topm@127.0.0.1/xe')
print (con.version)
con.close()
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-84-210d1be36a99>", line 2, in <module>
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('topm/topm@127.0.0.1/xe')

DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll is not the correct architecture". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help
```

Comment: Aparentemente você está utilizando um sistema operacional de 64 bits mas seu Oracle Client é 32 bits. Por gentileza, instale o Oracle Client na versão 64 bits no link https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está rodando arquiteturas diferentes do Python e do Oracle. Já que seu Pyhton é 64 bits, sua database também precisa ser 64 bits. Faça assim:

- Baixe o cliente 64 bits da Oracle e instale [aqui neste link](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html);
- Depois de instalar, para garantir atualize o
  pacote rodando o comando `python -m pip install cx_Oracle --upgrade`

Para saber se deu certo você pode rodar o seguinte teste:

```
# Use o diretório que você deszipou/instalou o instant client:
import os
os.chdir("C:\\Oracle\\instantclient_12_1")
import cx_Oracle
```

Se rodar sem erro deu tudo certo.

Comment: Obrigada Max, deu certo sim usando a minha base local, porem passei a stringde minha base de dados que ficar em outro equipamento, para acessar está base eu uso outro client onde o tnsnames ficar neste caminho C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\network\ADMIN mais mesmo passando o caminho ele dar erro no listener ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor, vou ver com o DBA se existe alguma particularidade, mais a sua solução foi ótima, agradeço e caso tenha alguma sugestão para está solução pode me enviar.

Comment: @AndressaM Como está a sua string jdbc? É aquela linha `jdbc:oracle....`

Comment: Max eu consegui conectar. Segue como ficou pra o servidor remoto:  #testa só a conexao
import os
os.chdir("C:\\oracle\\product\\10.2.0\\client_1")
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('topm/topm@10.10.10.152:1521/ tpdb.topm.local')
#(senha/usuário@IP do banco:porta/service_name)
#executa consulta
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('select * from produto where idproduto=100')
for result in cur:
    print (result[0])
cur.close()
con.close()